# Can't figure out how to define width of input box

Tags: php, html, css

I use joomla.  I can barely read php.  I'm using the following php code that I embedded into an article.  But the input box stretches across the whole article.  I want to limit the width to be centered and 75pix wide.  Here's the website I'm doing for a charity:  www.raleighsfinest5k.com
Here's the code I think is relevent:

```
  echo "$javaScript " . JText::_("Amount:") . " <span id=\"donate_symbol_currency\">" . $symbol . "</span><input type=\"text\" name=\"paypalamount\" size=\"5\" class=\"inputbox\" value=\"" . $paypalval_val . "\" />";
```

Any Help?

Comment: Do you know any HTML/CSS?

Comment: setting size would do the magic, but there might be probability of setting size elsewhere, you can set it as `size=\"anySize\" style =\"width:75px !important;\"` !important overrides all the later width property for this field.

Comment: template.css line 1185  your "input[type=text]" class in css has width 100%. Change it (but will change all). or do as above and do it in-line.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
     echo "$javaScript " . JText::_("Amount:") . " <span id=\"donate_symbol_currency\">" . $symbol . "</span><input type=\"text\" name=\"paypalamount\" size=\"5\" class=\"inputbox\" style=\"width:75px\" value=\"" . $paypalval_val . "\" />";
```

or add to your "inputbox" class in css

```
     width: 75px;
```